# Why are mezuzot always mounted on the right side of the doorway?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, mezuzah

I have read plenty regarding the debate on what direction and angle the mezuzah should be mounted. That said, I have never heard a clear explanation as to why we always mount them on the right side of the door frame.

Even in the Shema the text does not explicitly state "upper right quadrant of the door frame" when directing us. It simply states door frames in a general sense.

Do any of the sages give us clarity on why mezuzot were standardized to the right side? Is it something we have a clear answer for or is it simply the way it has been done so we don't question it?

Comment: https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4160450

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gemara [Yoma (11b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.11b.9?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en) writes:

> אֶלָּא, ״בֵּיתֶךָ״ לְמָה לִי? כִּדְרָבָא, דְּאָמַר רָבָא: דֶּרֶךְ
> בִּיאָתְךָ, וְכִי עָקַר אִינִישׁ — כַּרְעֵיהּ דְּיַמִּינָא עָקַר
> בְּרֵישָׁא.  The Gemara then asks: Rather, why do I need the emphasis
> of the verse: Your house, if every house is obligated in the mitzva of
> mezuza? The Gemara answers: This could be understood in accordance
> with the opinion of Rava, as Rava said: Your house is interpreted to
> mean that the mezuza is placed in the way that you enter the house.
> And when a person lifts his foot to begin walking, he lifts his right
> foot first. Therefore, the mezuza is affixed on the right side of the
> doorway.

Comment: Refer also to the Sefer HaChinuch Mitzvah 423 - https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.423.3?ven=Sefer_HaChinukh,_translated_by_R._Francis_Nataf,_Sefaria_2018&lang=bi

Comment: Note lefties still put on the right side

Comment: @Double I'm assuming your clarification was in regards to left footed people.

Comment: @user yes (footedness is different from handedness in chalitza as well for instance)